# Position two <span> elements next to each other

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two separate `<span>` elements that are currently appearing on top/below each other. I want to have them appear side by side. I've read a bunch of answers like this, and the solution was to use `float` but it just isn't working for me (maybe my HTML/CSS is off?) I want to be able to display/slide additional text once the user hovers over that specific button.

HTML:

```
<div class="skills">
      <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h1>Tutoring</h1>
                    <p>Weekly one on one tutor, teaching concepts of object oriented programming and introduction to game design with Java and the Dr. Java IDE</p>
                    <button type="button" class="round-button" onclick="clickTutoring()">
                        <span>></span>
                        <span class="button-hover">Click here to learn more</span>
                    </button>
                    <!-- ...other things here... -->
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.round-button { 
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    text-align: center;
    background: #464646;
    outline: none;
  }

.button-hover {
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #464646;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Hide the Click Here text upon loading the webpage
    $('.button-hover').hide();

    //Upon hovering, text will show across the across
    var buttonHover = $(function() {
        $('.round-button').hover(function() {
            $('.button-hover').toggle('slide');
        });
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now define your

```
.round-button { 
      position:relative;}
```

and 
 this

```
.button-hover {
        display: inline-block;
      vertical-align:top;
      position: absolute;
        left: 35px;
      top:5px;
    }
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Hide the Click Here text upon loading the webpage
    $('.button-hover').hide();

    //Upon hovering, text will show across the across
    var buttonHover = $(function() {
        $('.round-button').hover(function() {
            $('.button-hover').toggle('slide');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.round-button { 
    display: block;
  position:relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    text-align: center;
    background: #464646;
    outline: none;
  }

.button-hover {
    display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #464646;
  position: absolute;
    left: 35px;
  top:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="skills">
      <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h1>Tutoring</h1>
                    <p>Weekly one on one tutor, teaching concepts of object oriented programming and introduction to game design with Java and the Dr. Java IDE</p>
                    <button type="button" class="round-button" onclick="clickTutoring()">
                        <span>></span>
                        <span class="button-hover">Click here to learn more</span>
                    </button>
                    <!-- ...other things here... -->
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use row on your button for this too.

```
 <div class="skills">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h1>Tutoring</h1>
                    <p>Weekly one on one tutor, teaching concepts of object oriented programming and introduction to game design with Java and the Dr. Java IDE</p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <button type="button" class="round-button" onclick="clickTutoring()">
                            <span>></span>
                        </button>
                        <span class="button-hover">Click here to learn more</span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- ...other things here... -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have fixed the width for the button. Because of that your span text going to show in next line. Move your span outside of the button area. Also apply `display:inline-block` for you button.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="round-button" onclick="clickTutoring()">
    <span>></span>                        
</button>
<span class="button-hover">Click here to learn more</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.round-button { 
display: inline-block;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
line-height: 30px;
border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
border-radius: 50%;
color: #f5f5f5;
text-align: center;
background: #464646;
outline: none;
}

.button-hover {
display: inline-block;
padding:5px;
color:#fff;
white-space:nowrap;
background-color: #464646;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c6ogjdhh/)

Answer (score 0):

Change

`display: block;`

to

`display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

You have the `span` elements inside a `button` that is forced to be only `40px` in width so the content is dropping after it can't fit.  If you were to set `overflow:hidden` on the `button`, you'd see the rest of the content disappear.  If you just want to have the arrow in the circle, then target that with the `height`, `width`, and `border-radius` properties instead.